# How should I list a single role spanning two employers?

Tags: resume

I worked for a company for several years. During my time there, for reasons which I won't go into, my employment switched from Company A to Company B. I was given formal paperwork terminating my employment at A, and starting again at B. Nothing at all changed in my day-to-day employment: same role, same product, same people, same building. The only change was in the legal entity which employed me.

How should I list this on my resume?

<sub>Related (but not exactly the same, I don't think): [How to list a mashup of employers on resume when working for different companies that are the same company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/how-to-list-a-mashup-of-employers-on-resume-when-working-for-different-companies)</sub>

Comment: Where you would normally show the company name, I would either put "Company A/Company B" or more likely just "Company B" if there is no particular prestige to be gained by having worked for Company A. I certainly wouldn't create 2 separate employer sections unless it provided a means to highlight particular skills that the hiring company is looking for.

Comment: My company got bought (the latest in a long line of M&As in the company's history), and I went through a similar termination and re-hire as the old company was legally dissolved. I tweaked my resume simply by lumping the two into a single work item, listed as my employment with "New Company (formerly Old Company)" for which I held the same job title and performed the same duties. Employers understand well that the company one is employed at can change under one's feet (ironically however, my healthcare company still struggles with the idea that I've been insured continuously the whole time).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can also happen as a result of an acquisition, which is my current situation.  I list each employer separately, but for the newer one I start by connecting it to the previous one and I note the acquisition in the older one, such as:

> Company B (...)
> Expanded on my work at Company A to (blah blah blah)
>
> Company A (...)
> (normal entry here, ending with:)
> Company A was acquired by Company B in (year).

If any significant time has passed you *should* be able to say something meaningful in each entry.

If instead this happened because, let's say, you were a contractor who then got hired directly, it makes more sense to combine them because the contracting was a means to an end, not the primary goal (I assume).  In that case, you can combine them in one entry by doing something like this:

> Company B (previously Company A, under contract)

Comment: If the continued experience on a single skill/experience is the main point, you can just make a single title for both: ***Company A (2002-2004), Company B (2004-2006)** -or- **Company A, Company B (2002-2006)** Created Widget C.* This makes it clear that the job was the same for an unbroken period, even if it spanned two companies. At worst, the company will ask you why, but I think any company would be hard pressed throwing out a resume for something like that (if it actually was a continuation of the same job)