# How should I represent working for multiple companies for one job on a resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, employer

I'm currently looking at updating my resume, and I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out how to represent my current job situation. Last year I started contracting with Company A. Company A basically dealt with two different markets, X and Y. My work related to market X. Then I got an offer for full time employment from Company A, which I accepted.

Shortly after I started on as a full-time employee Company B spun off from Company A. I was transferred over to this new company. My work did not change at all, I still worked on projects related to Market X. Probably the biggest personal change for me was getting a new email address.

So how do I represent this on my resume? I think people would get the most accurate impression of my job if I listed the time frame as working for Company B. Company A now deals mainly with Market Y, and I have not really done any work related to Market Y. But the beginning date of my current job would then end up being before Company B existed. So I really don't want to do that.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11940/325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making this too complicated.  First you worked for company A, then you worked for company B.  List it that way with the appropriate start/end dates.

In the description of your duties for company B (which should be listed first since employment history should be in reverse chronological order), explain what you do.  You can also explain that B was spun off from A.

For your duties for A, you can either use a abbreviated version of what you wrote for B, or refer to the B description outright, explaining that at that time, A did what B does now.  It would be good to mention you left A to go to B because B was spun out of A.  That wouldn't count as a job "hop" against you then.

However, take a deep breath and step back a little.  This isn't that big a deal.  Mostly those reading the resume just want to see what kind of work you did and how often you hop around.  If the work looks relevant but the details a little confusing, they either won't care or will ask you about it later.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a simpler and more accurate way of describing my work there

Comment: Alternatively "Company B (formerly Company A)"