# Citing Multiple Projects for One Employer

Tags: resume, hiring-process, recruitment, human-resources

I have worked for an IT consulting company for the past year or so. I have worked on multiple projects (in-house, start to finish) for many different clients. I'm looking for an elegant way to list the different projects I've worked on, but still portray to the reader these were all done while I was working with X company.

I was thinking something like what is shown below, but am not sure of the correct verbiage and format.

```
X Company Consulting (2012-2014)
Role: .Net Dev
Projects include:
      A Company (Jan '12 - Apr '12)
      // blah blah
      B Company (May '12 - Feb '13)
      //blah etc
```

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24318/how-should-i-represent-working-for-multiple-companies-for-one-job-on-a-resume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use to work for a consulting company, so I worked with many different companies with many different teams.

I don't feel that dwelling on the many different contracts on your resume is a good use of the space nor will it give the reader a good summary of what you did.

Instead, have a line explaining what sort of consulting work "X Company" does. After that, have a line that states something along the lines of: "worked on over five different contracts with varying team sizes and project scopes."

After that, you can give a few points on what you did specifically over all jobs. I'm willing to bet that there was a great deal of overlap for most, but for the shining points, spell them out. "Managed a team of x people and was company liaison between our staff and Company A's personnel."

Or something to that effect. Highlight what you did, not that you worked on a lot of contracts.