# How to cite two different projects for one employer

Tags: resume, career-development, human-resources

How do I go about listing two separte projects for the same employer on the resume? My first project was implementing web services for a java enterprise application, and second project was implementing APIs for Android. Projects don't relate to each other so I cannot take approach suggested by [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34222/citing-multiple-projects-for-one-employer) thread. At the moment I have both projects listed as bullet points.

```
Company Name
-First project
-Second project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to just include the project names, with a single line explanation of each in the employment section, like this:

> Software Engineer at XYZ (June '11 - July '15)
>
> ________Your responsibilities, etc go here_____________
>
> Projects led/been a part of (<-- whichever is relevant)
>
> 1. **Project1's name:** implemented web services for a java enterprise application.   (<-- Only a single line)
> 2. **Project2's name:** implemented APIs for Android.

Then, in the **Projects** section, include the Projects with 3-4 bullets about each project.

This would help projects get noticed as part of your experience in the company, as well as let you include them with details.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. If I apply the suggested method then would I have to modify my previous experience as well? Since my previous jobs are listed more in terms of bullets and not in a separate project section.
Background: All my professional experience is as software engineer intern. My previous internships had one project per internship, however my current internship had two projects. Also currently under my projects section I have my personal and academic projects.

Comment: No, you don't have to modify previous experience. A simple difference would be this exp. would have a single line. For example: **Have led/been a part of ___Project1___ and __Project2__**

Include the projects details in the **projects** section, rather than in the **experience** section.
The Experience section, should just have the company name, your role, and the names of the projects.