# How to list multiple staffing agencies but same employer?

Tags: resume

I'm going through a rough patch at the moment due to layoffs within the company I work for. I'm trying to figure out how exactly I should put the job on my resume.

I originally interviewed with the company directly who made the decision to hire me, but my W-2 was through a staffing agency. Some time through my employment, the employers consolidated everyone to be under the same staffing agency, so I had to fill out all of the paperwork so that I was officially under another staffing agency. The employer still maintains full control of the staffing arrangements.

Additionally, the agency that I work for (not the staffing agency) contracts our work to another company, for which we actually support this other company in question. As the company is globally known, is there a place I could appropriately put this information?

How would I go about listing this on my resume? A few ideas I had:

> Employer
>
> Employer (Staffing Agency 2)
>
> Employer (Staffing Agency 1, Staffing Agency 2)

However I'm not sure which one is "appropriate". [I can see ideas for a company aquisition](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11940/how-should-i-list-a-single-role-spanning-two-employers), but I don't know if I would be following the same principle.

Answer (score 5):

If you worked for "Employer" all the time, I would put it like:

- 2005-2014 Big Well-Known Employer

  - '05-'08 through Staffing Agency 1
  - '09-'12 through Staffing Agency 2 and Staffing Agency 1
  - '13-'14 through Staffing Agency 2

It would show you continuously worked for the BWKE, and if they need references, they can contact the staffing agencies as listed.

Not sure about the exact wording, for example "through", I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Nice thinking :)

Comment: What about the situation where my employer contacts our team to a client? My W-2 is through Staffing Agency 2, I work for Employer A, but the work is done for Big Well Known Company B, at their office. Would this work for the first line?
```2005-2014 Employer A, client: Company B```

Answer (score 2):

As an employer, I do **not** care through which agency you worked.  I only care about the achievements you had and the skills you demonstrated.

If these were different roles within the company, I would list them as

- Junior Foobar Developer (2010-2011)
- Foobar Developer (2011-2012)
- Head of Foobar Strategy (2012-2014)

If you were doing the same job for the entire time - with no change in responsibility - list it as

- Foobar Technician (2010-2014)

And list your responsibilities.

A CV is an advert.  Everything on there should go to helping the next employer choose you.  The particular agency you worked through does *not* fall into that category.

If the new employer wants to take up references, that's the appropriate time to give them the name of the agencies.

Answer (score 0):

You were an employee of the staffing agencies. If as part of checking your employment history a potential employer were to contact the well known company, they would be told you never worked there.

This is not an unusual situation, on two occasions I have changed companies but still kept the same desk at the customer site. In the narrative you can explain that you supported a contract for company X, or government agency Y.

2013-Present

- Serve as the senior on site developer for ...

2012-2013 Staffing Company B

- Served as the senior developer on a contract with...

2010-2012 Staffing Company A

- Provided programming services for a contract with ...